# Which is faster, Brawler Claws or Raptor Claws? (No speed modifiers)

Tags: kid-icarus-uprising

I have Brawler Claws and Raptor Claws, and the Raptors seem to be faster and hit harder. Are Raptor Claws faster?

Answer (score -1):

Brawler Claws allow you to move the fastest of any weapon, modifiers aside. Raptor claws probably hit harder though.

Comment: It's helpful if you can cite why you believe this.  Did you read this somewhere?  Where?  Are you comparing statistics given in the game?  Where did you find them?  Is this based on observation?  What did you observe and how did you draw your conclusions?